# rspec for chef resources

Tags: rspec, automation, chef-infra

I am new to rspec and I tried to write a spec test my cookbook, but it's failing. When I tried to test "chef exec rspec", it's unable to find resources and outputs: "No Chef resources found, skipping coverage calculation...".

Here is the code and the spec:

```
group sq_group do
  system true
end

user sq_user do
  gid sq_group
  system true
end
```

the above code is for group and user and below is my rspec for testing user and group.

```
require 'spec_helper'
ChefSpec::Coverage.start!

describe 'recipes::default' do
  context 'Mostly defaults' do
    let(:chef_run) do
      ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new(platform: 'platform_name') do |node|
        default['cookbookname']['user'] = 'user'
        default['cookbook']['group'] = 'group'
      end.converge(default)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You have no test, as you're defining the chef_run as a 'lambda' with `let` nothing will happen before you add a test. Something along the line of: `it 'converges successfully' do
      expect { chef_run }.to_not raise_error
    end`

Comment: Thanks @Tensibai so do I need to include this line below describe?

Comment: The `it` block should be within the describe block (and after the context block), did you read ChefSpec README and examples on https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec ?

Comment: Do you have any idea about above error @Tensibai

Comment: [edit] your question to update the spec file with addition and the error in a readable manner please

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume your recipe is called "user.rb" and you will have following spec for it:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'lecturio_ds::user' do
  context 'When all attributes are default, on an unspecified platform' do
    let(:chef_run) do
      runner = ChefSpec::ServerRunner.new
      runner.converge(described_recipe)
     end

    it 'creates group' do
      expect(chef_run).to create_group('sq_group')
      .with(
         system: true
       )
    end

    it 'creates user' do
      expect(chef_run).to create_user('sq_user')
      .with(
         gid: 'sq_group'
         system: true
       )
    end

    it 'converges successfully' do
     chef_run # This should not raise an error
    end

  end
end
```

When you create new recipe you should use `chef generate recipe cookbooks/[cookbook_name] [recipe_name]` and you get auto-generated rspec file for your recipe that you need to fill with proper testing.